# Como desativar o CSS do WooCommerce do tema do zero que criei?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, woocommerce

Olá, estou encontrando problemas ao utilizar o WooCommerce do WordPRess. Criei um tema do zero, mas ao instalar o WooCommerce toda a parte visual que construi foi alterada pelo plugin WooCommerce. Gostaria de resolver isso, verifiquei o seguinte site: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/ mas eu não soube usar, adicionei alguns trecho de codigo desse link no meu 'functions.php' e nada. Exclui o WooCommerce.css mas sem sucesso e até mesmo desativei e exclui o plugin mas o site se permaneceu no estilo do WooCommerce. Como posso usar o WC sem afetar o visual do meu site ? como posso fazer a compatibilidade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dentro da tag head (A ultima linha), Cole isso, editando o nome do arquivo css

```
<?php
$css=mt_rand();
echo '
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="pasta/Seutema.css?'.$js.'"> 
';
?>
```

NO HTML fica assim:

```
<head>
//linhas anteriores

<?php
$css=mt_rand();
echo '
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="pasta/Seutema.css?'.$js.'"> 
';
?>

</head>
```

SE NAO RESOLVER, RETIRE DO HEAD E COLOQUE NA ULTIMA LINHA DA TAG BODY
FICA ASSIM:

```
<body>
//linhas anteriores

<?php
$css=mt_rand();
echo '
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="pasta/Seutema.css?'.$js.'"> 
';
?>

</body>
```

ASSIM ELE VAI FORÇAR A LEITURA DE SEU CSS. AO CONCLUIR A LEITURA DA PAGINA.

Comment: SE A RESPOSTA LE FOI UTIL. MARQUE COMO ACEITA.

Comment: FUNCIONOU AI AMIGO?

Comment: Opa, obrigado ! Desculpa a demora. Eu não testei, eu acabei encontrando o problema ! O problema foi o seguinte, ao instalar o WooCommerce ele ativou o tema do WC sozinho, assim, desativando o meu, a unica coisa que fiz foi ativar novamente e voltou ao normal ! kk

Comment: Poste sua solução pra galera ver. Pode ser que seja util para outra pessoa.

Answer (score 0):

Pra quem passou pelo mesmo problema que eu, uma possivel solução é você verificar o seu tema ! Ao instalar o woocommerce, ele desativou o meu tema sozinho, fazendo com que o do WC fosse ativado, assim, é só ir em 'aparencia > temas ' e ativar o seu tema novamente ! Valeu